# C# stack backing WPF ItemsCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stack

So I've just started trying to add a drop down undo feature to an existing application. The undo items are on a stack and I would like to be able to use that stack as my ItemsSource in a Listbox or similar control at the front end. I know that such a collection should implement INotifyCollectionChanged, and so far I have had to extend the Stack class while implementing INotifyCollectionChanged. However this has ended looking like a bodged mess, and I was wondering if anyone had any advice of a better way to proceed.

Comment: Why not use a plain ObservableCollection? It allows to add and remove items at any index position.

Comment: Yes. An **ObservableCollection** would do the trick. It implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` internally.

Comment: I did that. I had to swap out all the internal logic for updating the stack to deal with an ObservableCollection, but it appears to be working, thanks :D